# chrome content script to access and modify window

Tags: google-chrome-extension, sandbox

I am writing a chrome extension that is a 'content script'

I want to inject a google map on to a webpage.

**Problem**:
It appears that i have no way to add functions on to the `window` object, thus i cannot define a callback function for googlemaps to call when it loads.

How do people usually go about mucking with the `window`?

--
someone on the interwebs suggested i do this:

> You can do this easily with a JavaScript URL: window.location =
>   "javascript:obj.funcvar = function() {}; void(0);"

but when i did this i got an `access denied` error. it seems like a lot of search results about this problem are outdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Content scripts have a [separate JavaScript execution ennvironment](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment) from the page they run on, so they cannot alter JS variables in the page itself.  However, the content script shares the DOM with the page, so you can [inject a `<script>` tag](http://javascript.about.com/library/bladdjs.htm) into the DOM which will be loaded and run in the actual page's execution environment.